# Does use of NSAIDs prolong recovery time from febrile illness?

Tags: medications, fever

My understanding's that fever's an immune system response to pathogens. Would suppression of this response delay time to recovery?

Comment: I love this question. I too had it pop into my head once, years ago, when I had a fever and then suppressed it with Tylenol. Wondering if suppressing the symptoms of the immune response would prolong recovery time. I never found a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are studies that state reducing a fever may prolong illness. Fever can increase T-cell proliferation and cytotoxic activity. A study in 1990 showed that acetaminophen and aspirin increased symptoms and made viral shedding last longer. While that doesn't exactly address the role of NSAIDS I would think it would be the same as aspirin and acetaminophen. [Source: Is Breaking the Fever Bad? Fever Suppression May Be Detrimental by Catherine Moss](https://www.decodedscience.org/breaking-fever-bad-fever-suppression-may-detrimental/43607)